# NLTK classify interface using trained classifier

Tags: python, nltk

I have this little chunk of code I found [here](http://streamhacker.com/2010/05/10/text-classification-sentiment-analysis-naive-bayes-classifier/):

```
import nltk.classify.util
from nltk.classify import NaiveBayesClassifier
from nltk.corpus import movie_reviews
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def word_feats(words):
    return dict([(word, True) for word in words])

negids = movie_reviews.fileids('neg')
posids = movie_reviews.fileids('pos')

negfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'neg') for f in negids]
posfeats = [(word_feats(movie_reviews.words(fileids=[f])), 'pos') for f in posids]

negcutoff = len(negfeats)*3/4
poscutoff = len(posfeats)*3/4

trainfeats = negfeats[:negcutoff] + posfeats[:poscutoff]
testfeats = negfeats[negcutoff:] + posfeats[poscutoff:]
print 'train on %d instances, test on %d instances' % (len(trainfeats), len(testfeats))

classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(trainfeats)
print 'accuracy:', nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier, testfeats)
classifier.show_most_informative_features()
```

But how can I classify a random word that might be in the corpus.

```
classifier.classify('magnificent')
```

Doesn't work. Does it need some kind of object?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: Thanks to @unutbu's feedback and some digging [here](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.probability.ProbDistI-class.html#samples) and reading the comments on the original post the following yields 'pos' or 'neg' for this code (this one's a 'pos')

```
print(classifier.classify(word_feats(['magnificent'])))
```

and this yields the evaluation of the word for 'pos' or 'neg'

```
print(classifier.prob_classify(word_feats(['magnificent'])).prob('neg'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(classifier.classify(word_feats(['magnificent'])))
```

yields

```
pos
```

The `classifier.classify` method does not operate on individual words per se, it classifies based on a `dict` of **features**. In this example, `word_feats` maps a sentence (a list of words) to a `dict` of features.

Here is [another example](http://nltk.org/book/ch06.html) (from the NLTK book) which uses the `NaiveBayesClassifier`. By comparing what is similar and different between that example, and the one you posted, you may get a better perspective of how it can be used.